# How do I change display scaling dynamically?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have two monitors on my system, a 4k monitor (built-in) and a 1080p monitor (external). Obviously, this causes some issues with scaling due to the fact that windows often have weird sizes and are just in general *weird*.

I've been able to resolve this issue (partially) by setting my 4k monitor to downscale to 1080p (using 1x scaling), but it reverts to 4k when I unplug my other monitor. Usually, this would be awesome, but it doesn't change my scaling factor to my preferred 2x.

Is there a way I can configure my system to drop my builtin display to 1080p @ 1x scaling when I have my external monitor connected, and re-increase it to 4k @ 2x scaling when there's no other monitor plugged in?

---

To explain the underlying issue better (in case this is interpreted as an X/Y problem -- which it is), setting my laptop monitor to 4k @ 2x scaling makes things look good on it, but any window I open on it and drag to my 1080p monitor is double-size. For example, the Unity control center is about as big as my 1080p screen in this setup. This is obviously *really bad*, forcing this half-solution.

If there's a way I can keep my other monitor at 4k @ 2x scaling while keeping windows normal sized, I'd definitely appreciate a solution like that a lot more, but I think this is an X/GTK restriction, forcing the workaround I'm currently using. I've asked this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878376/why-is-xrandr-not-letting-me-scale-my-display) if anyone wants to take a grab at that.

Comment: hm, commenting just to share my experience. I tried using xrandr and stumbled upon this script http://digitalexpl0it.com/index.php/blog/displaylink-dock-ubuntu

Comment: Is the command to do so the issue, or to automate it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Really, any means to an end here. Command, script, obscure setting, etc.

Comment: Commands should not be the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The scaling factor is stored in the `KScreen` section of `~/.config/kdeglobals` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067987/366575) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026798/366575).

KDE can be restarted using [some combination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out) of:

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell
kwin --replace &
kstart5 plasmashell
```