# change Kubuntu laptop display scale

Tags: kde, screen, scaling

I' ve install the kubuntu 18.04 into my HP ZHAN 99 G1. At first it display in 1080P and have no scaling(maybe, because it have tiny logo and tiny font), but after I have tried to install latest Nvidia driver(apt-get install nvidia-xxx) and reboot several times, the windows and desktop go into about 125% scaling which makes everything looks bigger than before. Then I tried to change the theme and the status bar went into the same look. I want to have an original 1080P display without scaling. Any help?

BTW, newly installed driver successfully makes the screen lightness adjustable. But I don' t know how it works.

Answer (score 5):

This solved my problem:

- Go to **System Settings >> Fonts**
- Enable *Force fonts DPI*
- Change the setting to your liking (in my case: 96)
- Reboot

Answer (score 5):

Normally, these settings are in Settings --> Display and Monitor --> Displays --> Scale display.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is still useful in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers by @Bruni and @KDEuser are correct. Both are needed. The actual UI look is combined from both, the font scale factor from the fonts section, and the scale display.

When you find newer Java applications, Qt/KDE applications, fonts, icons, and window borders too big, change the font dpi. You find it in *System Settings* ⇒ *Appearance* ⇒*Fonts* ⇒ *Fonts* ⇒ *Force fonts DPI*.  Increase the font dpi to make things bigger, decrease the font dpi to make things smaller. Typical values are 96 for regular screens and 192 for HiDPI screens like QHD+ or UHD/4K. If you want to change a textfile instead, it's the value `forceFontDPI` in `~/.config/kcmfonts`.

When you find applications like chromium-browser and other non-KDE applications scaling wrongly, change the screen scale factor. You find it in *System Settings* ⇒ *Hardware* ⇒ *Display and Monitor* ⇒ *Displays* ⇒ *Scale Display*. If you want to change a textfile instead, it's the values `ScaleFactor` and `ScreenScaleFactors` in the section `KScreen` of `~/.config/kdeglobals`. If you use different screens with different resolutions and sizes, you can configure different scale factors for different screens. However, this is not supported for all applications, and it will not size different parts of the same window differently if a window is split between multiple screens. It's the origin (top left corner) of the window that counts.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE all monitors are scaled together in ~/.config/kwinrc

> [Effect-zoom]
> InitialZoom=1.23